# EventBus in vue not working

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a Laravel (5.4) application with some Vue components in it. I would need to make some of those components communicate, so I decided to add an EventBus. The code is the following:

app.js:

```
import VueResource from "vue-resource";
import Vue from "vue";
import Menu from "components/src/core/Menu.vue";

import MapWrapper from "./components/MapWrapper.vue";
import PaymentModal from "./components/PaymentModal.vue";

require("../sass/app.scss");

Vue.use(VueResource);

Vue.component("map-wrapper", MapWrapper);
Vue.component("my-menu", Menu);
Vue.component("payment-modal", PaymentModal);

// eslint-disable-next-line
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
});
```

event.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";

const EventBus = new Vue();

export default EventBus;
```

component that should trigger the event:

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <button @click="emitEvent">Click me</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";    
import EventBus from "../event";

export default {
    methods: {
        emitEvent() {
            console.log(EventBus);
            EventBus.$emit("testEvent", "test");
        },
    },
};
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

component that should receive the event:

```
<template>
    <div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import EventBus from "../event";

export default {
    computed: {
        test() {
            EventBus.$on("testEvent", ($event) => {
                console.log("event triggered", $event);
            });
        },
    },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

The problem is that when I click the button I can see the EventBus logged by the console, but nothing else happen, the receiving components does not catch the event.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should create EventBus on app.js before defining Vue components.

```
Vue.use(VueResource);

window.EventBus = new Vue();

Vue.component("map-wrapper", MapWrapper);
```

Isn't necessary to import EventBus later if using this approach.
Just use EventBus.$emit and EventBus.$on everywhere you want!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Did as you told but same problem :(

Comment: Here is working example!

https://jsfiddle.net/4do5ng92/

Looks like you should add EventBus.$on listener on your component's mounted() method like I did.

Comment: Yes! That was the problem! I put in created() and now it's working! Thanks!

Comment: In my case i was creating an EventBus object as new Vue in both the parent and child component and child was not responding. I guess by creating EventBus in app.js only once does the trick.